# Inno Setup 'Close' button in titlebar doesn't work when 'Cancel' button is not visible

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I removed *Cancel* button this way:

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  WizardForm.CancelButton.Visible := False;
end
```

But it also broke the close functionality of installer - *'Close'* button in titlebar does not work and installer doesn't react to <kbd>Alt+F4</kbd> keys. I know, there is `AllowCancelDuringInstall=no` directive, but it doesn't work either. Is it possible to hide *Cancel* button preserving ability to close the installer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Indeed, ability to close the installer is linked to state of the *Cancel* button. It makes sense, right?*

Anyway, if you really want this strange setup, you can achieve it by moving the *Cancel* button out of the view and preventing it from receiving focus using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.CancelButton.Left := ScaleX(-100);
  WizardForm.CancelButton.TabStop := False;
end;
```